# API As New Processor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been given the project of fixing a program that was being worked on by another employee before they left. Part of what I need to change is an API that sends an XML file what I need to change is where this file is going to. For example it used to go to google.com and now it goes to https://google.com. The code that's giving me problems is.

```
Dim API As New Processor("https://google.com", 86, "97", 30000)
```

what it used to say is

```
Dim API As New Processor("google.com", 86, "97", 30000)
```

I'm not sure why but it does not like the https:

the error I am getting is
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

and this is the stack trace:

```
[SocketException (0x2afc): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found]
   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) +8238680
   System.Net.Dns.Resolve(String hostName) +201
   Enterprise.XTrans.Processor.setIPEndPoint() +261
   Enterprise.XTrans.Processor..ctor(String ServerIP, Int32 ServerPort, String CompanyKey, Int32 TimeOut) +172
   uc_PayAuthorization..ctor() in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\uc\PayAuthorization.ascx.vb:85
   ASP.uc_payauthorization_ascx..ctor() in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\uc\PayAuthorization.ascx.vb:912304
   ASP.customer_aspx.__BuildControlPayAuthorization() in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Customer.aspx:555
   ASP.customer_aspx.__BuildControlpanLeft() in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Customer.aspx:156
   ASP.customer_aspx.__BuildControlconLeft(Control __ctrl) in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Customer.aspx:155
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.InstantiateInContentPlaceHolder(Control contentPlaceHolder, ITemplate template) +103
   ASP.dashboard_master.__BuildControlcphLeftContent() in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Dashboard.master:109
   ASP.dashboard_master.__BuildControlform1() in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Dashboard.master:48
   ASP.dashboard_master.__BuildControlTree(dashboard_master __ctrl) in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Dashboard.master:1
   ASP.dashboard_master.FrameworkInitialize() in C:\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Dashboard.master.vb:912308
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +1197
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +67
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +18
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +62
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1120
```

The Processor class is

```
#Region "Assembly XTransProcessor, Version=1.4.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1516eae9737b52e7"
' \\USASPDEV02\Inetserv\CRMDashboard\Bin\XTransProcessor.dll
#End Region

Namespace Enterprise.XTrans
    Public Class Processor
        Public Sub New(ServerIP As String, ServerPort As Integer, CompanyKey As String, TimeOut As Integer)

        Public ReadOnly Property ResponseData As String
        Public ReadOnly Property RequestData As String
        Public ReadOnly Property RequestXml As String
        Public Property NetKey As String
        Public Property EncryptionMode As EncryptionModeType
        Public ReadOnly Property TimeOut As Integer
        Public ReadOnly Property CompanyKey As String
        Public ReadOnly Property ServerPort As Integer
        Public ReadOnly Property ResponseXml As String
        Public ReadOnly Property ServerIP As String
        Public ReadOnly Property LastError As String

        Public Sub ResetObjects()
        Public Sub AddEncryptionKey(Key As String)
        Public Sub SetValue(KeyName As String, KeyValue As String, attributes() As TransactionAttribute)
        Public Sub SetValue(KeyName As String, KeyValue As String, AttributeValue As String)
        Public Sub SetValue(KeyName As String, KeyValue As String, Base64 As Boolean)
        Public Sub SetValue(KeyName As String, KeyValue As String)
        Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()

        Public Function ProcessRequest() As String
        Public Function Build() As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: You need to look at the code for the `Processor` class and see what its doing.  We would have no way of knowing, from your post, what that particular class was all about.   My guess is, given the stack trace, that the `Processor` class is building the URL itself.

Comment: Sorry that's part of what I find confusing when I open the class its labeled from metadata and I cant do anything in the class I will edit the original post and include that.

Comment: The first 3 lines at the top tell you what assembly that class is in, and where on the drive the assembly was compiled - or at lease referenced from.

Comment: You can assume from the name of the first argument to the `Processor` .ctor that the class is NOT expecting a URL.

Comment: You may end up needing to find the source code to the Processor class and update that.  To add to what Sam Axe was saying, check out this MSDN on the exact method that is blowing up on you (DNS.Resolve): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.resolve(v=vs.110).aspx